# Microsoft Access + Embedded OpenLayer Map

Tags: ms-access, openlayers-3

We have a Microsoft Access App we use out in the field when inspecting properties. We are building/adding an embedded.html file that uses OpenLayer to display a map showing our current geolocation and our destination. After we finish an inspection, we select the next property in our route list and it's highlighted on the map.

How do we communicate the selected property to the embedded map without reloading the map each time?

Mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0xC0.png

#### Current Solution

Currently, we embed the map using Access's web control. Each time we select a record, Access reloads the embedded map and passes the upcoming property via an append to the URL.

Pseudo Code URL: `C:\Applications\Inspection App\map.html?highlight:address123`

This is very slow, especially on the road where we use cellular data.

#### Desired/Potential Solutions

Our goal is to pass a new property to the embedded map each time we select a new record *without* reloading the map.

Two hypothetical options I'm aware of are:

1. Designing the .html file and passing the URL in such a way that that full page isn't reloaded.
2. Using Microsoft Access Visual Basic to pass a message to the .html file that it can use.

Comment: You could upload your mockup to imgur.com then post a link

Comment: Thanks, added a link to imgur.

Answer (score 0):

My company uses MS-Access extensively and I embed OL3 maps in pretty much all of the applications we use.

The method I use to communicate with the map without having to refresh the page is to write a JavaScript function that MS-Access then executes, either by button press, tab change, etc...

Assuming your Web Browser Control is called "WebBrowser", this would fire the specified JavaScript function.

```
Private Sub ExampleButton_Click()   
  WebBrowser.Object.Document.parentWindow.execScript "javascriptFunctionYouWishToExecute(" & Args & ")", "JavaScript"
End Sub
```

I've yet to find an elegant solution to get the reverse working, other than writing to a hidden HTML div and having MS-Access read that via a timer.

Comment: Great solution. We will use this going forward!